# Creating matrix of "concord" results

Tags: matrix, stata, matrix-multiplication

I have matrix with 400 rows and 40 columns.

I would like to create a new matrix from this data where I calculate the concordance between 2 variables, i.e., concord [A1,B1]=number1; concord [A1,B2]=number2; [A1,B39]=number39. So, number1 should now be the first number of the first row of a new matrix; number 2 is the second number in the first row....

The end result is a new matrix that shows the rho_c for each pair of numbers in the original data matrix.

The original matrix has a lot of empty cells. I can also create multiple matrix of subsections of concordance calculations, it doesn't matter much. However, I don't quite understand how to write this command in mata.

I've searched here: http://jasoneichorst.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/BeginMatrix.pdf

EDIT: The data looks like this (variable "Score1" is a rater). Not all raters rate the same item.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKwTw.png)

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something. When I read the question, it sounds like you are asking for a measure of concordance between two numbers (not variables)? Presumably Lin's Concordance Correlation Coefficient? But how do you measure correlation between two different numbers? That is like asking "What is the correlation between 5 and 7". Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I didn't write it correctly. It is the Concordance between two variables. And then I'd like a matrix with Lin's CCC for all the variable pairs.

Comment: Any particular reason you want a solution involving matricies written in Mata as opposed to operating on variables in Stata?

Comment: No. I just don't know another way to compare the relationships. I'm looking for how similar these raters are... looking for outliers, looking for raters who really do not agree.

Comment: I added a pic of the data for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I fully understand the question, there are methods to do this. One which comes to mind involves the use of `concord` available from SSC (`ssc install concord`) along with some local macros and loops.

```
/* Clear and set up sample data */
clear *

set obs 60

forvalues i = 1/6 {
    gen A`i' = runiform()
}
replace A2 = . in 10/L
replace A3 = . in 1/5
replace A3 = . in 20/L
replace A4 = . in 1/20
replace A4 = . in 30/L
replace A5 = . in 1/15
replace A5 = . in 40/L
replace A6 = . in 1/40

/* End data set-up */

  * describe, varlist will allow you to store your variables in a local macro
qui describe, varlist

local vars `r(varlist)'

  * get number of variables in local macro vars
local varcount : word count `vars'

  * Create a matrix to hold rho_c
mat rho = J(6,6,.)
mat rownames rho = `vars'
mat colnames rho = `vars'

  * Loop through vars to run concord on all unique combinations of A1-A6
  * using the position of each variable in local vars to assign the var name
  * to local x and local y
  * concord is executed only for j >= i so that you don't end up with two sets
  * of the same variables being ran (eg., A1,A2 and A2,A1)
forvalues i = 1/`varcount' {
    local y `: word `i' of `vars''
    forvalues j = 1/`varcount' {
        local x `: word `j' of `vars''
        if `j' >= `i' {
            capture noisily concord `y' `x' 
            mat rho[`i',`j'] = r(rho_c)

        }
    }
}

 * Display the results stored in the matrix, rho.
mat list rho
```

The above code should get you started, but there may need to be changes made depending on exactly what you want to do.

You will notice that inside of the loop, I have included `capture noisily` before `concord`. The reason for this is because in the image you linked to, your variables were missing values across entire sections of observations. This will likely result in an error message being thrown (specifically, r(2000): no observations). The `capture` piece forces Stata to continue to execute the loop if an error occurs there. The `noisily` piece tells Stata to display the output from `concord` even though `capture` was specified.

Also, if you search `help concord` in Stata, you will be directed to the help page which indicates that the concordance correlation coefficient is stored in `r(rho_c)`. You can store these as individual scalars inside the loop or do as in the example and create a kxk matrix of values.

Comment: In addition to this very helpful answer, note that the version of `concord` from  st0015_6 (`search concord` to see this) supersedes that on SSC. This is turn is also documented in `njc_stuff` (SSC).

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @ander2ed This worked great with "concord"; however, when I tried to do the exact same thing with "alpha" for creating a matrix with Cronbach's alpha for each pair, stata gives me an error with "too few variables specified" and "weights not allowed". Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: I suspect "too few variables specified" is a result of the loop executing `alpha A1 A1`. It will need to be updated to execute only for `j` strictly greater than `i`. As far as weights go, did you add anything else to the estimation command? Perhaps a new question would be appropriate if we begin to deviate from the question and answer here.

Comment: @ander2ed you were correct, it was a problem executing `alpha A1 A1`. However, using "alpha" I get the exact same values as `concord`. Isn't that strange? I can start a new question, but I'm not exactly sure what to title it now... (sorry, new to the forum).